# Extract multiple substring patterns from a vector

Tags: r, regex

Let's say I have a vector as follows:

```
patient_condition <- c("Pre_P1","Post_P1","Enriched_Post_P1","Post_P1_2","Pre_P2","Post_P2", "P3_Pre")
to_match <- c("P1","P2","P3")
```

I want to create another vector such that the new vector only contains value in to_match if it is a substring.

```
[1] "P1"  "P1"  "P1"  "P1"  "P2"  "P2"  "P3"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What if the string is `Post_P1_P2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
stringr::str_extract(patient_condition, "P[0-9]+")
#[1] "P1" "P1" "P1" "P1" "P2" "P2" "P3"
```

---

**Misc Replies**

> In my case, this answer works. but I guess the question I ask is extracting substrings from a vector given some values to match. Meaning this answer won't work if I want to extract characters (i.e. Pre, Post, Enriched, etc)

```
to_match <- c("Pre", "Post", "Enriched")
```

In that case, we can use

```
## R-level loop through `to_match`
tmp <- t(sapply(to_match, stringr::str_extract, string = patient_condition))
tmp[!is.na(tmp)]
#[1] "Pre"      "Post"     "Enriched" "Post"     "Pre"      "Post"     "Pre"
```

or

```
## convert multiple matches to REGEX "or" operation `|`
stringr::str_extract(patient_condition, paste0(to_match, collapse = "|"))
#[1] "Pre"      "Post"     "Enriched" "Post"     "Pre"      "Post"     "Pre"
```

[ThomasIsCoding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72958176/4891738) using `gregexpr` + `regmatches` is also a good alternative.

Note that this is doing **exact** substrings matching.

Answer (score 2):

You could `grep` then `rep` according to the `lengths`.

```
Map(rep, to_match, lengths(sapply(to_match, grep, patient_condition)), USE.NAMES=FALSE) |> unlist()
# [1] "P1" "P1" "P1" "P1" "P2" "P2" "P3"
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `regmatches` to extract the desired patterns

```
> regmatches(patient_condition, gregexpr(paste0(to_match, collapse = "|"), patient_condition))
[[1]]
[1] "P1"

[[2]]
[1] "P1"

[[3]]
[1] "P1"

[[4]]
[1] "P1"

[[5]]
[1] "P2"

[[6]]
[1] "P2"

[[7]]
[1] "P3"
```

Comment: since each string contains only one result, use `regexpr` instead of `gregexpr`

Answer (score 0):

more generally you can use `match`

```
lookup <- c("Pre_P1","Post_P1","Enriched_Post_P1","Post_P1_2","Pre_P2","Post_P2", "P3_Pre")
to_match <- c("P1","P1","P1", "P1", "P2", "P2","P3")
patient_condition <- c("P3_Pre", "Post_P1", "Enriched_Post_P1")

result <- to_match[match(patient_condition, lookup)]
[1] "P3" "P1" "P1"
```